# Can't get constant values for flex sensors

Tags: arduino, sensors

I'm working on a project to build a flex sensor glove which is supposed to interprete the sign language. To do that I need to attach 5 flex sensors. 2 flex sensors respond according to how much I bend them, so they are working fine but the 3rd sensor (4th and 5th also does the same thing) behaves as if I am constantly bending it. The values I am getting are normal for the 1st and 2nd sensors but the value for 3rd sensor keeps changing.

I wanted to use the simplest code to see if my sensors are working properly.

```
int flexPin1 = A0;
int flexPin2 = A1;
int flexPin3 = A2;
int value1; 
int value2;
int value3;

void setup()
{ 
 Serial.begin(9600);      
 pinMode(flexPin1,INPUT);
 pinMode(flexPin2,INPUT);
 pinMode(flexPin3,INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
 value1 = analogRead(flexPin1);        
 value2 = analogRead(flexPin2);  
 value3 = analogRead(flexPin3);  

 Serial.println(value1);
 Serial.println(value2);
 Serial.println(value3);
 delay(1500);
}
```

A sample from the values I am getting:

- 498 (Value I'm getting from the first sensor)
- 530 (Value I'm getting from the second sensor)
- 72   (Value I'm getting from the third sensor)
- 1.5 seconds delay
- 498 (first sensor)
- 530 (second sensor)
- 198 (third sensor) -> Althought i didn't bend it, third sensor changed its value. 1.5 seconds later it gives me something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be on the hardware side and not in the software. I don't see why the same code should behave differently for different sensors. Try hooking up the third sensor to the A0 and see if the problem still occurs. If it does on A0 then the problem is definitely on the sensor side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried that for each sensor but they are all working fine. Problem always starts with hooking up more than 3 sensors.

Comment: Ok that seems really strange. Can you try to put a short delay of about 10ms after every operation that reads a value?